# How to acces to the data from several json objects inside an array position

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm making a little app in nodejs, I'm struggling trying to print some data provenient from a json which has the following structure:

```
{
"courses": [
    {
        "java": [
            { "attendees": 43 },
            { "subject": "Crash course" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "python":
        {
            "occurrences": [
                { "attendees": 24 },
                { "subject": "another crash course" },
                { "notes": "completed with issues" }
            ,
                { "attendees": 30 },
                { "subject": "another crash course" },
                { "notes": "completed with issues" }
            ]
        }
    }
],
}
```

If I want to print the attendees at 'java' I do:

```
console.log(myJSON.courses[0]['java'][0]['attendees']);
```

which prints

```
43
```

and if I want to print the notes of the 2nd occurrence of the python course I do:

```
console.log(myJSON.courses[1]['python']['occurrences'][2]['notes']);
```

which prints:

```
completed with issues
```

The before mentioned cases are correct, but what I want to do is to print the keys of 'java' ('attendees' and 'subject'), as you can see Java is an array and in its unique position it has two json objects, I've tried with:

```
console.log(myJSON.courses[0]['java'][0].keys;
```

and with

```
console.log(myJSON.courses[0]['java'].keys;
```

but they print "undefined" and "[Function: keys]" respectively.

What I'm missing here?

Could anybody help me please?:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myJSON.courses[0]['java']` is an array with indexes. Where each index holds an object with keys. Your array doesn't exactly have the keys you want (the keys of an array are its indexes: 0, 1 etc...)

Instead, you want to access all the keys from the objects in the `myJSON.courses[0]['java']` array.

You can do this by using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). `.map` will allow you to get and convert every object in your `myJSON.courses[0]['java']` array. `Object.keys()` will allow you to get an array of keys from the given object (in your case your array will be of length 1, and so you can access index `0` of this array).

```js
const myJSON = {courses:[{java:[{attendees:43},{subject:"Crash course"}]},{python:{occurrences:[{attendees:24},{subject:"another crash course"},{notes:"completed with issues"},{attendees:30},{subject:"another crash course"},{notes:"completed with issues"}]}}]};

const myKeys = myJSON.courses[0]['java'].map(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0]);
console.log(myKeys);
```

If you have multiple keys in your objects within an array, you can also use [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (take note of browser support):

```js
const myJSON = {courses:[{java:[{attendees:43},{subject:"Crash course"}]},{python:{occurrences:[{attendees:24},{subject:"another crash course"},{notes:"completed with issues"},{attendees:30},{subject:"another crash course"},{notes:"completed with issues"}]}}]};

const myKeys = myJSON.courses[0]['java'].flatMap(Object.keys);
console.log(myKeys);
```